# How to handle build path sources when using 'templating-maven-plugin'

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm migrating from Ivy+Ant to Maven and I'm quite new to Maven so bear with me...

I need to 'filter' a single source file (.java) containing a placeholder for @@replaceme@@, then compiling the result and JAR the whole thing. I have managed to do the filtering for source file using *org.codehaus.mojo:templating-maven-plugin*. The plugin creates generated-sources into *${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java-templates* with the java-file content replaced as the way it should, then the compilation is correctly done and everything is working just the way it should.

**BUT**, in IDE (Eclipse) the build path source points now to *${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java-templates* = target/generated-sources/java-templates. I don't want that to be my primary build path source because now it contains replaced data, and would need the this to point directly to original source 'agent/src'.
If I add the original source 'agent/src' into POM (and that way visible in IDE), then the compile will fail due to duplicate class errors.

The relevant parts of POM:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter-src</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>filter-sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <delimiters>@@</delimiters>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <sourceDirectory>agent/src</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java-templates</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>loader/src</source>
                                <!--<source>agent/src</source> duplicate class -errors with this-->
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>test/src</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And this is how Eclipse is showing me source code now that it is 'missing' the original source code 'agent/src':

[image: Eclipse]

What am I doing wrong or is it just meant to be this way this plugin? I'm feeling in my guts that there is a really easy solution for my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this...:

The key was to separate the 'java-templates' from src-folder (I guess the folder name won't matter as it can be set by ) and then creating the same package structure under the 'java-templates' as the original file in src structure did have.

Ended up with POM:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>filter-src</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>filter-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <delimiters>@@</delimiters>
                        <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                        <sourceDirectory>agent/java-templates</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java-templates</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>loader/src</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>test/src</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And currently project looking like this:

[image]

------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------

Inspired by @khmarbaise answer, I actually did refactore the source structure to be more like Maven standard - moved agent/src & loader/src to src/main/java and by this way I was able to use 'templating-maven-plugin' with default values just the way @khmarbaise suggested.
Also removed 'build-helper-maven-plugin' and used 'templatin-maven-plugin' in POM by:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>filter-sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

By then my project looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove build-helper-maven-plugin
2. Remove configuration for sourceDirectory and outputDirectory from the configuration of templating-maven-plugin
3. Removed the definition of the phase from templating-maven-plugin, also definition of the id

Put your template class into `src/main/java-templates/<package>`

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>templating-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>filter-sources</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

That's all what is required... Oh just define the version in pluginManagement or explicitly in the above setup.